# Op-Amp Summing Amplifier Not Working

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, negative-feedback

I have this below circuit op-amp summing amplifier with its below result:

[image]

But in my actual circuit all components are the same except the op-amp.
I am using this [op-amp](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbos038/sbos038.pdf?ts=1605786044746&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) part in my practical circuit :

V1 - 22V
V2 - 1V pk-pk Sine Wave
Output Voltage - 20V

Output Current - 50mA.

Actual Circuit Output Waveform :

[image]

Why am I not getting the summed output as in the case of simulation result?

Comment: Maybe you have the two inputs swapped or some other mistake in your new diagram?

Comment: If the Vin+=Vin- within Vcm range then it is wired OK, yours is not. But where is the 50mA load?

Comment: You haven't mentioned V3 in the actual implementation. How close is the output V to the actual supply?

Comment: Output is same as the Vcc. I am not sure what is the mistake I am making over here. I have verified all the connections.

Comment: You have a 32 V supply voltage. The op-amp has a maximum input voltage of 4 V below V+. But your input 1 V is near 40 V. Probably you have blown something up.